# Responsive Styling for Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, joomla3.0

I am currently designing a site for my brother using Joomla 3.4 and Bootstrap. This is the first time I will be building a responsive site and wanted some advise on what to make sure I have within my CSS i.e. font sizes in particular units.

I am aware that I will need to use media queries to target each viewport, but one thing that confuses me is trying to workout what sizes would sit well for a smartphone, not sure if theres a guide list to follow to help me out.

If somebody could please advise, would really appreciate it.

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap grid, it will be responsive by default, all media queries are already set so the site will scale according to resolution.

Comment: Also, don't set breakpoints to devices. Make your site respond to the content. If something doesn't look right at a given size, change it. Chasing the ever-changing and expanding landscape of device sizes will only get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, you should use its Grid System

> /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */ /* No media query
>   since this is the default in Bootstrap */
>
> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */ @media (min-width:
>   @screen-sm-min) { ... }
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */ @media (min-width:
>   @screen-md-min) { ... }
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */ @media (min-width:
>   @screen-lg-min) { ... }

and here is the [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) you can check more on.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, really appreciate it  : )